# MySQL - summing up products from several orders

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to sum up the number of items purchased from several orders. I have this query, however it shows me each order on a separate row. I want have it all added up in one row. This is woocommerce database.

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(m.meta_value, ' x ', i.order_item_name) separator '</br>' )
    FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items i
    JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta m ON i.order_item_id = m.order_item_id AND meta_key = '_qty'
    WHERE i.order_id = p.ID AND i.order_item_type = 'line_item') AS 'Items'
FROM  wp_posts AS p
JOIN  wp_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
JOIN  wp_woocommerce_order_items AS oi ON p.ID = oi.order_id
WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
```

Example output:

```
2 x item1</br>2 x item2</br>1 x item3
4 x item1</br>5 x item2</br>3 x item3
```

and this is how it should be:

```
6 x item1</br>7 x item2</br>4 x item3
```

Comment: Please provide sample data

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I think you just need to add group by.

Comment: Which table does the column post_type belong to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the aggregation string over all those items, so the aggregation must be the main query. Look up the desired order IDs with `IN` or `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(m.meta_value, ' x ', i.order_item_name) separator '</br>' )
FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items i
JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta m ON i.order_item_id = m.order_item_id AND meta_key = '_qty'
WHERE i.order_item_type = 'line_item'
AND i.order_id IN
(
  SELECT p.ID
  FROM wp_posts AS p
  JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
  WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
);
```

Maybe you can remove the join on `wp_postmeta` in the subquery. That depends on which table the column `post_type` resides in.

(I hope I got everything right. I just took your query and re-wrote it. I don't know the data model and I don't know if a post ID can really equal an order ID, but this is how you use them in your query.)

Comment: with this query I got a combined string with all orders in one row instead of counted products